# How to segment polygon in to line segment?

Tags: python, shapely, fiona

I want to segment a Polygon or PolyLine in segment of line and remove some segments. I have an polygon that i convert in polyline by the code below and it work well:

```
from shapely.geometry import mapping, LineString
import fiona as fn
import operator
from functools import reduce

with fn.open('multipolygon.shp', 'r') as source:
    source.profile['schema']['geometry'] = 'LineString'
    with fn.open('segment_line.shp', 'w', **source.meta) as sink:
        for feat in source:
            xcoords_poly = feat['geometry']['coordinates']
            liste_coords = reduce(operator.concat, xcoords_poly)
            lines = LineString(liste_coords)
            assert lines.is_valid
            assert lines.geom_type == 'LineString'
            feat['geometry'] = mapping(lines)
            sink.write(feat)
```

After this step i want to remove some segments (lines) of my polyline where they overlays with some polygons as this picture show it :
[image]

For doing that i make the code below :

```
# great function that i find here to get coords of geometry
def pair(list):
'''Iterate over pairs in a list -> pair of points '''
for i in range(1, len(list)):
    yield list[i-1], list[i]

to_del = []
fn_obs = fn.open('obs.shp')
with fn.open('segment_line.shp', 'r') as source:
    with fn.open('avoid_obstacle.shp', 'w', **source.meta) as sink:
        for f in source:
            geom_f = shape(f['geometry'])
            try:
                for ob in fn_obs:
                    xob = shape(ob['geometry'])
                    if(geom_f.intersects(xob)):
                        to_keep = []

                        for seg_start, seg_end in pair(geom_f.coords):
                            line_start = Point(seg_start)
                            line_end = Point(seg_end)
                            segment = LineString([line_start.coords[0], line_end.coords[0]])
                            if(segment.intersects(xob)):
                                to_del.append(segment)
                            else:
                                to_keep.append(segment)
                        new_seg = linemerge(to_keep)
                        f['geometry'] = mapping(new_seg)                       
                sink.write(f)

            except (Exception):
                logging.exception("Error type of file:", f)
```

And i got this results :
[image: Result i got]

It's like good but what i want it to remove all the line as this picture show it :[image]